# ignore OneTimeSetup and TearDown when tests runing locally

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit

I write automation tests in c# and check via NUnit.

Autotests are integrated with TestRail in such a way that each time tests are run locally, a test runs are performed in TestRail. All this is implemented like this:

OneTimeSetup:

```
public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            Client = new TestRailClient(Url, User, Password);
            var commandResult = Client.AddRun(_projectId, 2, "Selenium Test Run " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, "Selenium Test Run example", 1);
            Console.WriteLine(commandResult.Value);
            _runId = commandResult.Value;
        }
```

TearDown where results are sent:

```
 public void TearDown()
        {
            var id = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Description").ToString().Replace("C","");
            var result = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var testrailStatus = result switch
            {
                TestStatus.Failed => ResultStatus.Failed,
                TestStatus.Passed => ResultStatus.Passed,
                _ => ResultStatus.Retest
            };

            var resultForCase = Client.AddResultForCase(_runId, ulong.Parse(id), testrailStatus);
            Console.WriteLine(resultForCase.WasSuccessful);
       }
```

My task: I need to configure so that in TestRail, the test runs perfoming only when launched in TeamCity, and when I run tests locally, OneTimeSetUp and TearDown must be somehow ignored. 
In TeamCity tests run with *dotnet test* command 
How I can ignore OneTimeSetUp and TearDown when I start tests locally? 
Thanks!

Comment: Wrap them in `#if RELEASE` blocks?

Comment: Does TeamCity set any environment variables that can be used to identify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In appsettings.json or any other config that you are using - create a variable `Environment` with default value `TestRail`.

Then in hooks - get the value of this variable and if it's `TestRail` - init TestRailClient.

On local tests run - change `Environment` in config to `Local`.

You may also create appsettings.Development.json config and override `Environment` there. Depends on your config approaches.